# Result of multiplying a scaling matrix with a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I don't understand why if you multiply a scaling matrix with rotation matrix that the resulting matrix, when applied to a shape like an ellipse, only gets scaled and does not get rotated.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3.7 & 0 \\
0 & 2.1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
0.9510 & -.3090 \\
0.3090 & 0.9510
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you do the matrix multiplication the opposite way it does do both when the resulting matrix is applied to an ellipse.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: This is obviously false - take the unit scale matrix for example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could be "right" is for a rotation with  $\theta=n\pi/2$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z})$. If $n$ is odd you need a scaling that "reverses" the shape of the ellipse, in such a way that the major axis becomes the minor axis, and the minor axis becomes the major axis, with the same proportions as the original ellipse.

Comment: you just added an example, and say that the reverse is an actual rotation and scaling. That is surely wrong, perhaps some mistake in your calculations. Although, a look at your matrix looks that you are scaling the two axes by a different factor. That is not called scaling as far as I know.